# UPDATE table in SQL SERVER database with data in HIVE using Spark

Tags: sql-server, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have my master table in SQL Server and I want to update a few columns in the table based on the conditions that 3 columns matches between my master table (in SQL server DB) and target table(in HIVE). Both tables have multiple columns but I'm only interested in 6 columns as highlighted below:

The 3 columns that I want to update in my master table are

```
"INSPECTED_BY", "INSPECTION_COMMENTS" and "SIGNED_BY"
```

The columns that I want to use as my matching condition are

```
"SERVICE_NUMBER", "PART_ID" and "LOTID"
```

I tried the below code but it's giving me a NullPointerException error

```
val df = spark.table("location_of_my_table_in_hive")
df.show(false)
df.foreachPartition(partition => 
{
    val Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(SQLjdbcURL, SQLusername, SQLPassword)
    val batch_size = 100
    var psmt: PreparedStatement = null 

    partition.grouped(batch_size).foreach(batch => 
    {
        batch.foreach{row => 
            {
                val inspctbyIndex = row.fieldIndex("INSPECTED_BY")
                val inspctby = row.getString(inspctbyIndex)
        
                val inspcomIndex = row.fieldIndex("INSPECT_COMMENTS")
                val inspcom = row.getString(inspcomIndex)
        
                val signIndex = row.fieldIndex("SIGNED_BY")
                val signby = row.getString(signIndex)
        
                val sqlquery = "MERGE INTO SERVICE_LOG_TABLE as LOG" +
                    "USING (VALUES(?, ?, ?))" +
                    "AS ROW(inspctby, inspcom, signby)" +
                    "ON LOG.SERVICE_NUMBER = ROW.SERVICE_NUMBER and LOG.PART_ID = ROW.PART_ID and LOG.LOTID = ROW.LOTID" +
                    "WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET INSPECTED_BY = 'SMITH', INSPECT_COMMENTS = 'STANDARD_MET', SIGNED_BY = 'WILL'" +
                    "WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES(ROW.INSPECTED_BY, ROW.INSPECT_COMMENTS, ROW.SIGNED_BY)"
                var psmt: PreparedStatement = Connection.prepareStatement(sqlquery)
        
                psmt.setString(1, inspctby)
                psmt.setString(2, inspcom)
                psmt.setString(3, signby)
                psmt.addBatch()
            }   
        }
        psmt.executeBatch()
        Connection.commit()
        psmt.close()
    })
    Connection.close()
})
```

Here is the error

```
ERROR scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 4 
times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 9, lwtxa0gzpappr.corp.bankofamerica.com, 
executor 4): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at $anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(/location/service_log.scala:101)
    at $anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(/location/service_log.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at $anonfun$1.apply(/location/service_log.scala:74)
    at $anonfun$1.apply(/location/service_log.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2121)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2121)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$11.apply(Executor.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1408)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:413)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I searched the internet and could not find the reason why the error is coming.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this on spark cluster,I think you might have to broadcast some object. Executors not are able to get the value of the object so the null pointer exception.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Yes I'm running on a cluster. What object do you think i need to broadcast? Thanks as I await your reply.

Comment: @OpeBaba  not sure, but may be these SQLjdbcURL, SQLusername, SQLPassword.